Why am I getting an 'insufficient quota' error with OpenAI API despite not using my quota?
# Import required libraries
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from itertools import zip_longest
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_chat import message
import os
from langchain.schema import (
    SystemMessage,
    HumanMessage,
    AIMessage
)

# Load environment variables
load_dotenv()

# Set streamlit page configuration
st.set_page_config(page_title="ChatBot Starter")
st.title("ChatBot Starter")

# Initialize session state variables
if 'generated' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['generated'] = []  # Store AI generated responses

if 'past' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['past'] = []  # Store past user inputs

if 'entered_prompt' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['entered_prompt'] = ""  # Store the latest user input

if 'prompt_input' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['prompt_input'] = ""  # Store the current user input

# Initialize the ChatOpenAI model
api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
if not api_key:
    st.error("OpenAI API key not found. Please set the API key in your environment variables.")
    st.stop()

chat = ChatOpenAI(
    temperature=0.5,
    model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    openai_api_key=api_key
)


def build_message_list():
    """
    Build a list of messages including system, human, and AI messages.
    """
    # Start zipped_messages with the SystemMessage
    zipped_messages = [SystemMessage(
        content="You are a helpful AI assistant talking with a human. If you do not know an answer, just say 'I don't know', do not make up an answer.")]

    # Zip together the past and generated messages
    for human_msg, ai_msg in zip_longest(st.session_state['past'], st.session_state['generated']):
        if human_msg is not None:
            zipped_messages.append(HumanMessage(content=human_msg))  # Add user messages
        if ai_msg is not None:
            zipped_messages.append(AIMessage(content=ai_msg))  # Add AI messages

    return zipped_messages


def generate_response():
    """
    Generate AI response using the ChatOpenAI model.
    """
    try:
        # Build the list of messages
        zipped_messages = build_message_list()

        # Generate response using the chat model
        ai_response = chat(zipped_messages)

        return ai_response.content
    except Exception as e:
        st.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return "An error occurred while generating the response."


# Define function to submit user input
def submit():
    # Set entered_prompt to the current value of prompt_input
    st.session_state['entered_prompt'] = st.session_state['prompt_input']
    # Clear prompt_input
    st.session_state['prompt_input'] = ""

# Create a text input for user
st.text_input('YOU: ', key='prompt_input', on_change=submit)

if st.session_state['entered_prompt'] != "":
    # Get user query
    user_query = st.session_state['entered_prompt']

    # Append user query to past queries
    st.session_state['past'].append(user_query)

    # Generate response
    output = generate_response()

    # Append AI response to generated responses
    st.session_state['generated'].append(output)

    # Clear entered_prompt
    st.session_state['entered_prompt'] = ""

# Display the chat history
if st.session_state['generated']:
    for i in range(len(st.session_state['generated'])-1, -1, -1):
        # Display AI response
        message(st.session_state["generated"][i], key=str(i))
        # Display user message
        message(st.session_state['past'][i], is_user=True, key=str(i) + '_user')

st.markdown("""
---
Made with ❤️ by Rushikesh
""")

this error i get. error insufficient quota of api key so i search everywhere youtube,Documentation,github, replace code many time.  Any solution
try to do project on LLM and want to test Openai. so that's why i want to use the api_key for free. i thought problem in the api_key. also chatbot not give response of my question.
